# Cannot get IP address (Embedded Linux)

Tags: linux, network-programming, drivers

I have recently written a custom driver for a phy that is connected to an ARM processor running a Linux 3.8 kernel. I wrote the driver because I could not find a driver that supported the fiber interface on this phy in the open source community. My driver seems to be a little buggy but I am not sure why. Here is what I am seeing.

1) During boot I will get and IP address through DHCP (udhcpc in this case) only about 50% of the time. When I do not get an IP address I get this output from ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D4:F5:13:B8:86:E4
          inet6 addr: fe80::d6f5:13ff:feb8:86e4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1634 errors:0 dropped:436 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:114256 (111.5 KiB)  TX bytes:1112 (1.0 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr C4:12:D6:A1:7F:00
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

In the above case, `eth0` has Fiber connected to the Phy and `eth1` is disconnected. This is weird to me, because the `eth0`, and the `eth1` interfaces are different in `ifconfig` telling me that the kernel is noticing something different between the two interface.

When I use `ethtool eth0` I am being told that the Link is detected and am being told that the link is not detected fro eth1 (as expected).

What would cause ethtool to realize there is a link, but udhcpc not to be able to get an IP address?

Comment: eth0 has an ipv6 address fe80::d6f5:13ff:feb8:86e4/64 assignt. If this is not what you want, you should disable ipv6 on your system. Just guessing: if the dhcp response comes in the right time you get an address assigned otherwise you get an ipv6 address.

Comment: @sinclair I think I found the answer to that question from this post. The first response seems to sum it up. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2100982 I believe this means that it is not actually getting an ip address from DHCP.